# Is 404 error possible if we are hosting a website on github using indexx.html [double x in index]

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I am uploading a little project on my GitHub and it was throwing error of 404 so when I rename the indexx.html to index.html it stop giving the error

Comment: What is wrong with this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub Pages will look for an index.html, index.md, or README.md file as the entry file for your site. So you must make sure that your main files are index.html or it will return an error

You can learn about creating a GitHub Pages at
https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site